# Dialux screwing up blender model

Tags: modeling

Im modeling a surface 3d on Blender, and importing this in Dialux EVo.
But in some places the surface it's getting weird, pls see the img attached.
[image]
Why?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about using Blender.

Comment: what is the topology of that problematic green mesh in Blender? Looks like you might have to re-topoligise it.

Comment: well the topology is equal of the rest of the model.. this problem just happen in this place..

Comment: maybe its just a problem in Dia lux... that is not so good with 3d models

Comment: No, it is a problem with your model's poor topology

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tips for proper topology](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57891/tips-for-proper-topology)

Comment: i dont understand .. this happen just in some places.. all the rest of model was made by the same way of this places with problem